# degG(x) + degG(y) >= n, show that the graph is hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

I'm trying to show that a connected graph which has order >=3, and having the following inequality is Hamiltonian:

```
degG(x) + degG(y) >= n   x and y are two non-adjacent vertices
```

I know that Dirac's theorem will be helpful here, but I really don't know how to apply it. (Dirac's theorem: Let G be a graph of order n>= 3. If the minimum degree of graph G is >= n/2, then G is Hamiltonian).

Could you guys give me any hints? Thanks!

Comment: If memory serves me right, it's the other way around - the statement you are trying to prove _implies_ Dirac's theorem (which it clearly does), not _is implied_. Though I might be wrong here.

Comment: I think you should be able to modify the proof of Dirac's theorem to imply your statement.

Comment: Googling suggests that this theorem is attributed to Ore, and can be found here:  Ore, O.  A note on Hamiltonian Circuits.  Amer. Math. Monthly
 67 (1960), 55.

Comment: @KevinZ: Perhaps, ask such questions on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is true. It is a generalization of Dirac's Theorem known as [Ore's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem).

Comment: Nice link! What is en.m.wikipedia as opposed to en.wikipedia?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński I think the mobile version. I did copy and paste the url from on my phone. I changed the link, it should now go to the regular site (and mobile browsers should redirect appropriately).